# Append data to directives element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Building out a data table and there's 2 main functions

1. Sort the data table
2. Download what's viewable in sorted table into CSV

So far able to get the table sorted and can download a CSV using jQuery. However using jQuery is not the Angular way so need the ability to just use pure JS.

**Directive "exportToCsv"**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('exportToCsv', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = element[0];
        element.bind('click', function(e){
            var table = e.target.nextElementSibling;
            var csvString = '';
            for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length;i++){
                var rowData = table.rows[i].cells;
                for(var j=0; j<rowData.length;j++){
                    csvString = csvString + rowData[j].innerHTML + ",";
                }
                csvString = csvString.substring(0,csvString.length - 1);
                csvString = csvString + "\n";
            }
            csvString = csvString.substring(0, csvString.length - 1);
         // USING JQUERY ABLE TO DOWNLOAD THE CSV
         var csvExport = $('<a/>', {
                href:'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
                download:'report.csv'
          }).appendTo('body');
          console.log('variable jqueryExport', csvExport);
            csvExport[0].click();
            csvExport.remove();

        // UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD CSV USING ANGULAR ONLY
        var csvExport = ('<a/>',{
             href:'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
             download:'report.csv'
         });
        // Seems like all the answers want to append to HTML rather than it's own node
        element.append('csvExport');
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
...
<button export-to-csv>Download</button>
<table>...</table>
...
```

How would one go about appending the `csvExport` to it's element, download, and then remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a dynamic [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) that sets itself to the value of the csv.

Something like:

```
<table id="data-to-download">...</table>
<a ng-href="{{ dataUri('#data-to-download') }}" download="report.csv">Download</a>
```

Then just implement dataUri like you've got above, using the passed in selector ('#data-to-download').

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however wasn't able to get the data uri to pass through. Was able to tweak the jQuery way into Angular and keep everything contained in the directive with no extra markup.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to append the download link to the directive element.

**Angular Way**

```
var csvExport = angular.element('<a/>');
csvExport.css({display: 'none'});
angular.element(document.body).append(csv);

csvExport.attr({
  href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,'+btoa(csvString),
  target: '_blank',
  download: 'report.csv'
})[0].click();
```